# Order of callbacks when waking up app with BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

When my app wakes up because a bluetooth command was detected (in my case, finding a peripheral after setting up a scan), what is the order of the callback methods?

In particular, when is didDiscoverPeripheral actually called?

Is it:

1. application willLaunchWithOptions
2. application didLaunchWithOptions
3. CBManagerDelegate didDiscoverPeripheral?

Or are there no guarantees as to when didDiscoverPeripheral will be called?